# Filtering with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Currently I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productFeed>
        <product id="233004">
        <name><![CDATA[Van Bommel P2577]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Leren casual herensneaker met nopjes op de hiel van Van Bommel. Kleur: cognac.]]></description>
        <price><![CDATA[199.95]]></price>        <productURL>http://vanarendonk.cleafs.com/go?k=4upHUYcQalVXox0zikwnMgTagF73SwA5&amp;c=1190&amp;redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Evanarendonk%2Enl%2Fheren%2FVan%2DBommel%2FP2577%2D%2FCognac%2F120%2E13%2E6</productURL>
        <imageURL><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDEuanBn800733.jpg]]></imageURL>
        <additional>
            <category><![CDATA[schoen]]></category>
            <sub_category><![CDATA[heren]]></sub_category>
            <gender><![CDATA[heren]]></gender>
            <type><![CDATA[Sneakers]]></type>            <model><![CDATA[16102/02 751]]></model>            <brand><![CDATA[Van Bommel]]></brand>            <color><![CDATA[Cognac]]></color>            <topmaterial><![CDATA[Glad leer]]></topmaterial>            <insole><![CDATA[rubber]]></insole>                                    <size><![CDATA[41;42;42,5;43,5;44;45;46;47]]></size>            <size_UK><![CDATA[7,5;8;8,5;9,5;10;10,5;11;12]]></size_UK>            <image_1><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDEuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_1>
<image_2><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDIuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_2>
<image_3><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDMuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_3>
<image_4><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDQuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_4>
<image_5><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDUuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_5>
<image_6><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDYuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_6>
<image_7><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDcuanBn480440.jpg]]></image_7>
<image_8><![CDATA[http://www.vanarendonk.nl/update/images/120.13.6/.tmp/tmb.MTIwLjEzLjZfMDguanBn480440.jpg]]></image_8>
            <delivery_costs><![CDATA[geen verzendkosten vanaf 75,00]]></delivery_costs>
            <delivery_time><![CDATA[3 days]]></delivery_time>
        </additional>
    </product>
        ... 
<productFeed>
```

I want to filter this feed on the brand. I've tried:

```
/productFeed/product[1]/additional[1][contains(brand,'BRANDNAME')]
```

but this didn't give me any results.

Who knows how to filter this feed on only the brand name?
Are there any easy online tools who can do this? Have searched for it myself but couldn't find any.

Comment: Why can't you paste the xml here?  (did you try using the curly brace {} button?)  Try the tool XPath Builder here: http://www.bubasoft.net/

Comment: Have downloaded the tool, thanks for that tip. Cant paste it here because it is not displayed correctly. 
Where should I place the {}?

Comment: Don't type '{}' use the button with the '{}' to insert code and formatted text.

Comment: That is not working unfortunately. Link to the feed is here http://promo.swf.cleafs.com/xml/utf8/ikwnMgTagF73SwA5/9878/ (1171 elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it gets nodes with the substring Pant in the brand):

```
/productFeed/product/additional/brand[contains(.,'Pant')]
```